# how to select all columns without PRIMARY key in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I going to list all columns of a table except PRIMARY key in mysql.
Note : operation is automatically so I don't know the names of fields.
Can you help me for making this query?

Comment: This kind of question points to bigger problems with your design - usually revolving around normalisation (or lack thereof)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something worth doing some research on, if you are going to be working with databases in any length.

All DBMS I have worked with thus far have a means of looking at the constraints, columns, and table information.  The ones for MySQL that will help you do what you want are likely in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA:

[TABLE_CONSTRAINTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836502/how-do-i-show-unique-constraints-of-a-table-in-mysql) The MySQL Reference for this is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/table-constraints-table.html).

```
SELECT table_name, constraint_name, constraint_type FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.table_constraints;
```

[COLUMNS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726458/mysql-get-list-of-all-column-names-in-a-table-that-do-not-have-null-as-their-de) The MySQL reference for this is [here.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html)

```
SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns;
```

[KEY_COLUMN_USAGE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/key-column-usage-table.html)

You should be able to do something like this to get what you want:

```
SELECT INFORMATION_SCHEMA.key_column_usage.column_name 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.key_column_usage
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.table_constraints 
ON INFORMATION_SCHEMA.key_column_usage.column_name = INFORMATION_SCHEMA.table_constraints.column_name
WHERE INFORMATION_SCHEMA.table_constraints.constraint_type <> 'PRIMARY KEY'
```

The should be essentially what you need.  Views/tables like these can be your best friend when needing to get information about your schema.

I hope that this information helps.