# Select all columns except primary key in MySQL

Tags: mysql

How can I select all columns except the primary key from a table? It should be noted that I don't know field names in this table, the operation should be able to run automatically.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Can I ask out of curiosity why you would want to select everything BUT the primary key?

Comment: Please show your table definition. You can use `DESC <tablename>` to obtain the definition.

Comment: Possible Duplicate Of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122/select-all-columns-except-one-in-mysql

Comment: If you know at least the names of the primary key columns, the linked duplicate seems helpful.

Comment: @Thilo thanks for pointing that out. I was not 100% sure if that was a duplicate question, or enough to answer OP's so I just left a comment rather than flag it as duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to select all columns without PRIMARY key in mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26550801/how-to-select-all-columns-without-primary-key-in-mysql)

Answer (score -1):

Use:

To get All columns Without primary use

```
 SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS` WHERE (`TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'wpresstest') AND (`TABLE_NAME` = 'wp_countries') AND (`COLUMN_KEY` <> 'PRI')
```

**See you cant do all using simple SQL.So**

**Either use mysql Prepare Execute statement Or use PHP way like:**

1)This would be your 1st Query as above.You will get All column names Excluding primary.OK?

2)Now fetch the resulted array in `PHP`.and build dynamic query for Comma separated Column names you just got.

3)Now fire 2nd query to fetch ROWS .Here you will include `SELECT (Column1,Column2) from TBL`.

And after getting column names , you can fire query to return Result based on Returned columns

Comment: thanks, but this error returned :  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SHOW INDEXES FROM TABLE WHERE Key_name <> "PRIMARY") from tbl1' at line 1

Comment: @Behzad , updated answer, replace table,DB names by Your Own tables 

wp_countries , wpresstest

Comment: thanks a lot but again error :( ... I use this SELECT (SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS` WHERE (`TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'test') AND (`TABLE_NAME` = 'tbl1') AND (`COLUMN_KEY` <> 'PRI') ) FROM tbl1

Comment: and this error returned : #2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Comment: first use Simple select to fetch all COLUMNS without primary. then go for nested SELECT , wat did u get in Simple  SELECT?

Comment: @Behzad , can you plz work around it ? m in office having imp deployment.I cant answer half part of your question immediately.

Comment: I can't understand your text. could you write better?

Comment: Thank you. Query optimization is very important for me